# Getting error message of "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." when running multiple coded ui test cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Hi i'm running into an issue where i'm getting the error message "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used." when i run multiple codedui test case.

I see as i exit the first test case, that some how i see on the debugger the message "Multiple processes are being debugged ......".  I'm using one instance of the browser which i'm making static and attaching a process to the browser process so i don't really know why its happening or where i need to look.

I've debugged it numerous times.  I've found a work around but the work around is clumsy and involves me locating brower window and passing the obeject again.

I still want to know the reason for this error.  If anyone has ever dealt with this I'd appreciate some direction. Thanks

~W